# In the below c code , Error: 'subscripted value is not an array, pointer or a vector' on line 19 for avg[i]=sum[i]/5

Tags: arrays, c, syntax-error

so in the below c programming code i couldnt find out why i am getting the error 'subscripted value is not an array, pointer or a vector' on line 19 for avg[i]=sum[i]/5 , please help and explain how i can resolve this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)//main starts 
{
  int i,j;
  float mark_tot[]={0,0,0,0,0},sum[5]={0,0,0,0,0},avg[5];
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    char name[40];
    float mark[5],tot,avg;
    printf("Enter name : ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
      printf("Enter %d th mark of %s ",j+1,name);
      scanf("%f",&mark[j]);
      mark_tot[i]+=mark[j];
      sum[i]+=mark[j];
    }
    avg[i]=sum[i]/5;
    printf("Your name is %s,\nYour total is %f,\nYour average is %f,\n ",name,sum[i],avg);
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
      printf("%d th mark ",j+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `avg` is a `float` (`float mark[5],tot,avg;`), so `avg[i]` makes no sense.

Comment: You have two different variables named `avg`.  The one at the top level of `main` has type `float avg[5];`.  The one declared inside the `for` loop has type `float avg;`.  Change them to have different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens when you declare a float variable named "avg"(line 9), this variable take effect from line 7 to line 25, Even though you have an array variable "avg[5]". You may either declare a variable "avg_pointer" instead of "avg" and point it to "avg[5]" in line 9, or just remove "avg" in line 9 so that "avg[5]" has already taken effect in the function.